# What exactly is "pinning" in relation to indexes in DBMS?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, oracle

As part of a test question, students were asked to define and describe pinning in relation to indexes. When one talks about "pinning" in indexes, what exactly is this? Is there some other word/term I can search for, as google has not provided any solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a table or index is *pinned*, it means it is kept in memory.

The database has a certain amount of memory allocated to work with.  Typically, the database caches recently used data.

When an index is *pinned*, it means the index is kept in memory permanently, rather than being aged out of the cache.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for! Could you link to a more in-depth explanation please, as I have been unable to find anything?

Comment: Here's some Oracle info on the topic: http://www.jlcomp.demon.co.uk/faq/pin_table.html

Answer (score 1):

Pinning something in DBMS means to ensure that the thing is always kept in memory.

It is frequently used for hot indexes that see a lot of queries against them, but might aged out of Database cache and have to reload from the disk. By pinning the index in memory the index scan will theoretically never require a disk access.

Pinning results in substantial performance improvement in case of larger index because there is no need to frequently refreshing the cache.